# How to fix audio not auto playing when page is loaded? - html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play an audio when page is loaded, it should be really simple however i can't accomplish it.

The problem is that it is not playing, i tried checking the state of autoplay (True/False) and it says it does playing when page is loaded although it does not, also tried making a function which will change the auto play state to True but it didnt do anything ...

```
<html>
<head >
    <audio controls autoplay id='myAudio'>
            <source src="..//sounds//firstpagesong.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            <source src="..//sounds//firstpagesong.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</head>
    <body onload="tryy()">
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() 
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").autoplay;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            }
            function tryy()
            {
                var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
                audio.autoplay = true;
                audio.load();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Also looked up for similar question here and tried thier solution as well but none of them worked.

Comment: Try putting the `script` tag before the body.

Comment: `it does playing when page is loaded although it does not` because you didn't set it up to run on onload, also you need `x.load()` in `myFunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to play an audio when page is loaded, it should be really simple...

Yeah, well, it isn't.  Autoplay with sound is largely disabled in all mainstream browsers these days.

See also:  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes